# When testing an API - Should I test API methods validation?

Tags: tdd

I've inherited a project which will be connecting to a CRM system via a SOAP service, written by another dev. My question is: to what level should I be testing the interface with the Soap services?

I set up a test case and wrote some methods to test a Soap update method, and confirmed it failed with a suitable error code for invalid customers or order numbers.

I next tested an invalid order status value (not within in a set of expected parameters) and the service returned a success code, which wasn't expected.

I believe I should report this to the developer, but should I now remove this test from my test suite? Or leave it showing as a fail?

If the soap service chooses not to validate its imput parameters I think it's a poor design, but it's not a fault in MY code, I just need to ensure I clean the input before passing values to the other system, and that validation should be covered under another set of tests anyway.

Should I even be talking to the SOAP service through the Unit Tests in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the library (or 3rd party code) has a good reputation (for example, Apache Commons, Guava...), I don't retest the API.

However, when I am not sure of the quality of the code, I tend to write a couple of tests verifying my assumptions about the library/API (but I don't retest all the library).

If those simple assumptions fail, it is a very bad sign for me. In this case, I tend to write more tests to check more aspects of the library. In your case, I would write more tests and signal errors to the developer.

These tests are not lost, because if a new version of the library is delivered, you can still use them to check for regressions.

Comment: Thanks - So in the absence of dedicated unit tests for the actual API, you would leave this particular test (a parameter that is not in the expected set should be rejected) in place and failing, until the other dev fixes his code?

Comment: @user903182 Yes. In Java, there is a possibility to annotate tests with @ Ignore. The compilation just skips them. You can reactivate them later when a new version of the library is delivered. In fact, you can even send those test to the developer. He/she should include them in his/her own test set.

Answer (score 1):

You should write at least one test per atomic functional requirement.  Now, if you are writing using minimal interface guidelines, then you should have at most one interface per atomic functional requirement.  But you can write more than one test for each requirement, since there may be a variety of invariants that can be tested.

In general, you should think of invariants and functional requirements when writing tests, not interface methods.  Tests >= Atomic Functional Requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the service "contract", what are it's pre-conditions (i.e. legal inputs), it's post-conditions (i.e. legal outputs) and invariants (legal service state). If these are not clear by the developer, or there's a chance another developer is misusing the service, this should be reported and handled.

One exception though - these is all nice and good in theory, but if there are no other customers to the service (besides maybe the original developer) sometimes excess checking is obsolete. It is quite reasonable to assume that in such cases invalid inputs are checked and eliminated by the customer code.